# Simulate Cross Certification with xca

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, x509

i would like to simulate cross certification with XCA [0].

Like

> **Contoso Root CA**
>
> > -> Contoso InterCA
> >
> > > -> Bob
>
> **Super Root**
>
> > -> Bridge CA
> >
> > > -> X-Cert Contoso Root CA
> > >
> > > > -> Contoso InterCA
> > > >
> > > > > -> Bob

Creating single certs are not the problem, but im stucking at the point 'Contoso InterCA',
because this ICA has two issuers - 'Contoso Root CA' and 'X-Cert Contoso Root CA'.

I really dont know how to realise this.

Thank you in advance!

best regards,
Markus

[0] http://xca.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such things as two issuers in a certificate. The simple answer is that your ICA can have two certificates. One issued from 'Contoso Root CA' and one issued from 'X-Cert Contoso Root CA'.
When clients are verifying the certificate chain, they will/should use the certificate that chains up to their trusted root, be it 'Contoso Root CA' or 'Super Root'.